# Searching not only by post name but also category

Tags: wp-query, search

I have a catalogue of cars, where the post name is car model and category name is car brand.

When im using search like "BMW" it gives 0 results.

How can i make search work with post or category. My current code:

```
foreach ( $types as $type => $title ) {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'      => $type,
            's'              => $s
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $output .= '
            <p class="title">' . $title . ':</p>
            <ul>';
```

Comment: Are you using normal WordPress posts and categories, or are you using a custom post type and taxonomy?

Comment: i think it's custom post type, i'm a content manager but chief asked me to fix searching.. there is not "pages" on left bar of admin page but special section cars and models.. is it the answer? :)

Comment: You can find out if it is by looking for code like this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/complete-guide-custom-post-types/#creating-custom-post-types In order for us to help, we need more info like if it is a custom post type, what the custom post type is called, and what the taxonomy it is using is called. Otherwise the answers may not fit your site.